# Is this method for solving the limit of a composite function valid?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let's say we have these two functions:
$$f(x) = x^2$$

$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
-(x-2)^2+2,  & x<2 \\[2ex]
(x-2)^2-2, & x\ge 2
\end{cases}$$

And we want to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(g(x))$$

We can rewrite this as:
$$f\left(\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)\right)$$
so long as $f(x)$ is continuous at $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)$. What I was thinking was that although $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)$ doesn't exist, $\lim_{x\to 2^-}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^+}g(x)$ do exist. Thus, we can do this: 
$$f(\lim_{x\to 2^-}g(x))=f(2)=4$$$$f(\lim_{x\to 2^+}g(x))=f(-2)=4$$
$\require{AMScd}$
Since we get 4 for each case, $$\lim_{x\to 2}f(g(x))=4$$
Is the method I just used valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is valid, because you used continuity of $f$ to conclude that
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 2^-} (f \circ g)(x) = \lim_{x \to 2^+}(f \circ g)(x) = 4.
\end{align}
Since both one sided limits exist and are equal, the "full" limit also exists and equals $4$.